# BOOTP on Juniper 4200 stack works one one subnet, not another

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, juniper, bootp

I have a Juniper Stack that connects vlans 10,11 and 50. 10 is servers, 11 is desktops and 50 management.
Bootp is redirecting DHCP requests to a AD box on 10.x just fine for 50 vlan, and worked well for the 11 vlan for a few days then just stopped. Now if I look in the statistics I see that lots of packets are getting dropped for the reason "Due to missing valid local address: 575"

More information such as packet captures are included on my post on the [Juniper forums](http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Ethernet-Switching/DHCP-BootP-stopped-working-for-one-vlan-on-EX4200-4550-VC/td-p/212117)

I will give the switches a reboot this weekend, but as bootp is working for the 50 vlan I cant see why it wouldn't continue to work for the 11 vlan.

Config:

```
forwarding-options {
  helpers {
    bootp {
      description "Workstation/ Management Subnet DHCP";
      server 192.168.10.242;
      maximum-hop-count 4;
      interface {
        vlan.11;
        vlan.50;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain your vlan sub-interfaces match properly? It's not ALWAYS certain that vlan.11 refers to tag 11, and so forth.